# How to listen for eslint errors in ember dev server?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, eslint

I want to stop the local dev server in development in case of any eslint errors found. Is there any solution for this case? 
Please help me if there any there any solution.

Comment: why do you need this behaviour?

Comment: Please verify and upvote my answer if you find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop the local dev server when you get linting errors. I think that behaviour is not possible.

BTW you can always find the `eslint` errors in your terminal (in which `ember server` is running) when you save a file.

Apart from that, you can run `npm run lint:js` to find all the linting errors from the entire app.